# Updating column in a table from another table using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a two tables i need to copy from table 2 to table 1.
I want the **table 1. column departure** to be updated on the matching in table 2.

**Condition**
The table 2 have multiple items for the table 1,( table 1 have many relation with table 2). So in that case i need to sort it by `RotationOrder` and takes first row.

Table 1

```
Id  Code    Departure
479 JJ1256  NULL
480 SR1255  NULL
481 PFOBLEM NULL
482 SO1301  NULL
483 TS1302  NULL
484 YB1305  NULL
485 CU1303  NULL
```

Table 2

```
Id  Departure   RotationOrder    CanLoad
479 NULL    1       1
480 NULL    1       2                 1
481 NULL    1       3                 1
482 NULL    1       4
482 NULL    3
482 NULL    2
482 NULL    4
483 2013-01-21  1                     1
483 NULL    3
483 NULL    4
483 NULL    6
```

What i have tried

```
UPDATE table1 set Departure = (select top 1 table2.Departure from table2 
INNER JOIN table1 on table1.Id = table2.Id  where CanLoad =1 order by 
RotationOrder )
FROM TABLE1  INNER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.Id = TABLE2.Id
```

**Problem**
This query copy first null value from the table2 and paste it on table1. which is incorrect.

Comment: empty RotationOrder indicates null or empty string.?

Comment: RoationOrder have data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross apply top 1, beloved classic:

```
UPDATE t1 set Departure = q.Departure
FROM table1  t1
cross apply 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Departure
    FROM table2
    WHERE t1.Id=table2.Id
    ORDER BY RotationOrder asc
)q
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you'll want to do it:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Departure = T2.Departure
FROM Table1 T1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT ca.*
                  FROM Table2 ca
                  WHERE T1.Id = ca.Id
                  ORDER BY ca.RotationOrder) T2;
```

Notice the use of the table's alias in the `UPDATE` clause. If you use the table's actual name (not it's alias) you are technically declaring a 2nd `Table1`, which can/does produce odd behavior as it technically creates Cartesian product. It's therefore very important to use the syntax `UPDATE [Table Alias]` when using the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I dont see a order by clause in the query. Wont it takes arbitrary value from the second table

Comment: @Eldho why would a `UPDATE` statement need an `ORDER BY` clause? The order you update the rows is meaningless.

Comment: If i have more than 1 match in the joining table i.e, table 2 it should take first element sorted by the rotation order. How will achieve that

Comment: @Eldho This is why adding **expected results** is so important in your questions. :)

Comment: @Eldho changed to a `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Thank for the "Notice" comment, I edited my answer according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore null value rows. This assumes you have one non null row per Id

```
UPDATE Table1 set Departure = Table2.departure
FROM TABLE1  INNER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.Id = TABLE2.Id where Table2.canload =1 and Table2.deprture is not null
```

Comment: I cannot `Table2.deprture is not null ` if its null it should be updated too. How this will get the first element from table 2 is there are many matches.